# Style Gtk3 text caret

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, vala

Is there any way to change the style of the text caret (cursor) using gtk3/gdk in an application? I was wondering if there would be a way to change both the width and color of the caret in a text entry. Docs or solution in any language would work but vala or python would be preferred if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using either `gdk_cursor_new_from_pixmap ()` or `gdk_cursor_new ()` in combination with `gdk_window_set_cursor` on enter/leave/focus-in/focus-out events of your desired widget (make sure the widget tracks the cursor!) should work.

Comment: This should work with any widget, though I never tried with widgets that already change the cursor (i.e. text input widgets).